# Substracting in a while-loop that won't work | Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, while-loop

I'm doing this program where I'm given a certain Julian Date so I can calculate the sideral time in greenwich.
After doing the calculations GST can be a really big or really small value.
Part of the process is that I must (add or substract) GST by factors of 24 so that my value is between 0 and 24 (because its is a time).

I intented to do a while loop so that it kept substracting until it was a value between (0 and 24) but i don't seem to find a way it works.

```
T = (JD-2451545.0)/36525.0 
GST = 6.697374558 + (2400.051336*T) + (0.000025862*T*T) + (GMT*1.0027379093)

while GST>24:
    GST = GST - 24
    if GST<24:
        break
        print GST
```

Comment: You need to interchange the `break` and `print GST` statements.  Also, maybe you mean `while GST>=24:`. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `%` remiander operator. `%` operator divides first number with second one and returns the remiander and you are doing same. You are just removing 24 by a factor of 1 with each iteration and when it will become less than 24 i.e not further divisible by 24, you will break. You can get that exact same value with one line by finding remainder.

```
>>> 1000 % 24 = 16
>>> 199999 % 24 = 7
```

You will alway get a value less than 24. So if you want to get 24 as well, replace 24 with 25, i.e. one greater than the limit

```
>>> GST = GST % 24
```

Answer (score 3):

The program is working as it should. You don't see it as you break the loop before actually printing anything. Add `break` after the `print` statement.

Also, since `GST` is time, it cannot be equal to `24` (the hours go from `00` to `23`). I *suggest* changing your loop condition to slack inequality (`>=`) rather than a strict one (`>`).

```
while GST >= 24:
    GST = GST - 24
    if GST<24:
        print GST
        break
```

What you are trying to do can be achieved in a more efficient way by using the modulo (`%`) operator. So, the above block reduces to:

```
GST %= 24
print GST
```

Comment: What is significance of GST >= 24 condition. IMO @JacobIRR's solution is better if we go with this loop based approach. if condition is not needed if you change the while condition to `GST > 24`

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz I am not saying that there is something wrong with `>` or it is better to use `>=`. What I am saying is, since `GST` is time (hours, most probably), it cannot be equal to 24.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
while GST > 24:
    GST -= 24  # Trick for assigning GST to (GST-24) 

print GST
```

This will automatically break the loop once the condition is met. No `if` statement or `break` statement required.